# Phonegap Keyboard Events on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I need to detect when a keyboard key is pressed on an iPad/iPhone. I'm using phonegap 3.4.0 so it needs to be in javascript/html or a phonegap plugin. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just simply bind keypress event to document.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress",yourHandler);
```

in code above when a key is pressed, it will call yourHandler. The first parameter of yourHandler will be the keyboardEvent object which gives you the keycode, alt key status etc.